# Batch file to utilise VDesk utility in Windows 10 not working as expected

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting

I like to run multiple desktops on Windows - one for general use, one for web development, one for software development, one for language studies, etc. I would usually have one or two applications open per desktop, which I would keep open even if I wasn't doing anything on that desktop. For example, I'm going through an online course on HTML 5 and CSS, so for the web dev desktop, I like to keep open a Chrome window to that course as well as Visual Studio Code.

The problem I started running into is that whenever I needed to shutdown and/or restart (especially during Windows updates), I would have to manually set up my desktops with the apps I want kept open. So, I did some searching online (including asking on Microsoft forums) and found out a utility called [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk). I then wrote a batch file that runs at startup and uses VDesk to set up my desktops how I like them.

However, the batch file isn't working as it should, based on the usage laid out in the VDesk readme file. Here is my code:

```
@echo off

:: Apps to run on desktop 2
vdesk create:2
vdesk on:2 run:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /new-window "https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:W3Cx+HTML5.0x+1T2019/course/"
vdesk on:2 run:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"

:: Apps to run on desktop 3
vdesk create:3
vdesk on:3 run:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /new-window "https://www.udemy.com/kotlin-course/"
vdesk on:3 run:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /new-tab "https://github.com/dEhiN/kotlin-beginners"
vdesk on:3 run:"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\bin\idea64.exe"

exit
```

I found that if I run this batch file with just desktop 2, it works fine. Desktop 2 is created and both Chrome and VS Code are started on that desktop. The focus also goes to desktop 2, so I usually have to press Win key + Shift to go back to desktop 1, but everything works fine. However, when I added the commands to set up desktop 3, everything started on desktop 3. VS Code, IntelliJ, Chrome pointing to the HTML 5 course, a second instance of Chrome pointing to the Kotlin course with a second tab pointing to my GitHub page; all opened up on desktop 3.

Any reasons why? I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this, since from what I can tell, my code is correct. Should I perhaps have the batch file wait for a bit after executing the code for desktop 2? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently running into the same thing, the desktops arent getting created right when I add a second one,

```
ECHO Shall i run your Ctrader instances 
ECHO ... ?
PAUSE
vdesk create 2
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\Users\timsaenen\Desktop\IC Markets cTrader.appref-ms"
vdesk on:3 noswitch:true run:"C:\Users\timsaenen\Desktop\IC Markets cTrader.appref-ms"
ECHO
ECHO Loading completed.
PAUSE
EXIT
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the command not being finished, and I found this link that talks about exactly just that!

https://blog.modelworks.ch/efficient-desktop-environment-under-windows-10-using-virtual-desktops-and-vdesk/

So im going to try that  now, I'll let you know if it works :)

**Update**

So the results are much better when you apply a wait with the TIMEOUT command.
What also helped for me is removing the 'noswitch' argument.
I wanted to have them open in the background, but there is something odd with the way W10 selects to focus an  newly openend applications.  Still not happy with the way W10 handles the virtual desktops and the configuration options for multiple displays,but that's another story.  (recommend DisplayFusion should you face the same)

```
ECHO =====  Load Ctrader ?  =========
ECHO ================================= 
ECHO =================================
PAUSE
vdesk create 3
vdesk on:2 run:"C:\Users\timsaenen\Desktop\IC Markets cTrader.appref-ms"
ECHO =================================
ECHO =================================
ECHO == Loading .....=================
ECHO =================================
ECHO =================================
timeout /T 30
vdesk on:3 run:"C:\Users\timsaenen\Desktop\IC Markets cTrader.appref-ms"
ECHO =================================
ECHO =================================
ECHO ==== Loading completed ==========
ECHO =================================
ECHO =================================
PAUSE
EXIT
```